# Google calendar event in UTC time zone?

Tags: google-calendar

I am trying to create a calendar with some events related to a console game, specifically Destiny, and it has some fixed times each day, each week, and each weekend, where something happens.

These times are specified in UTC.

When creating a new calendar in Google Calendar I can specify that the calendar is in GMT+00 (no daylight saving) timezone:

[image: Calendar setting]

but is this possible for the events themselves? I have to pick a country and then a timezone, and I can't find any country that would seem obvious for this. Perhaps it isn't possible?

[image: Event setting]

**Note**: The question is not whether the time is correct right now, when I create the appointment/event, the question is how to keep it correct in the future if I make it repeating, sorry for not mentioning that. The events in the game happen every day, every week, and every weekend, so I'd like to create a calendar that shows this. The question is thus how to make the appoints follow UTC and not Norwegian time, which will change their relationship to UTC depending on daylight saving.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ghana (Accra) is GMT+0 all year round, so I use it to schedule events like teleconferences with participants on multiple continents.

Comment: So is Reykjavik, Iceland.

Answer (score 3):

At the suggestion of [this post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/y6uaiAdZrIg), here is at least a work-around:

- Go into 'Calendar Settings' in the upper right of the calendar page
- Under the 'General' tab in the "Your current time zone" section, select the 'Display all time zones' checkbox and then click on "Show an additional time zone"
- Scroll through the list to find "(GMT+00:00) GMT (no daylight saving)" and then click 'Save'
- Now, when you go to add an event in the calendar you can click "Time zone" and GMT will be in your list!

This also has the side-effect of making an additional "GMT+00" time column appear in the calendar page, next to your local time zone. You can change the label applied to this column in the settings page described above, in the "Label" field to the far right.

Answer (score 0):

Google Calender (and most shared calenders (Outlook)) will automatically update the date/time for the event for the recipient depending on their settings.
So if you put the event in your timezone and send it out; then it *should* all work out.

I would suggest to try out a couple just to make sure rather than missing something :)

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/2367918?hl=en

> How Calender Treats time zones
>
> Whenever you create an event, Calendar converts it from your time zone to UTC time, using currently known conversion rules. By using one universal time for all events, Calendar can keep all of your guests’ calendars consistent regardless of which time zones they're in. When we display the event on your calendar, it is converted from UTC to appear in your own time zone.

Comment: That's all well and good but if I put an 11:00 appointment into my own time zone, which is what is suggested, ie. the Norwegian time zone, will it keep current with my local time? Or will it move to 10:00 or 12:00 in the summer, depending on the direction daylight saving goes in Norway? Ie. will it keep to *my* time or the *utc* time after daylight saving transitions occur? (I think I know the answer btw)

Comment: I would suggest that you try it yourself (Can you talk to another member and send an invite directly to them to try it?)

I just created an event in GMT, and sent it to someone in India (IST); it was displayed in their calender as IST.

Google will take care of the time zones automatically.

(edited as didn't expect enter to save the comment)

Answer (score 0):

I did so:

```
    time_zone = 'Europe/Moscow'
    task_time_start_utc = task.date_time
    task_time_start_moscow = task_time_start_utc.in_time_zone(time_zone)

    task_time_end_utc = task_time_start_utc + task.duration.minutes
    task_time_end_moscow = task_time_end_utc.in_time_zone(time_zone)

    event_property = {
        summary: task.name,
        location: "#{task.lat} #{task.lng}",
        description: string_work_times,
        start: {
            date_time: task_time_start_moscow.to_formatted_s(:iso8601),
            time_zone: time_zone
        },
        end: {
            date_time: task_time_end_moscow.to_formatted_s(:iso8601),
            time_zone: time_zone
        }
     }
```