# Which country do I select for UTC+0 without daylight saving in Google calendar

Tags: google-calendar, time-zone

In [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67777/google-calendar-event-in-utc-time-zone), the following image shows a nice selection of GMT+0 without daylight saving. However this option seems to be missing from event timezones. How do I add a UTC time event in google calendar?

This is just to set the timezone when creating the event, and also not have it change when some daylight saving kicks in. I'm fine with it being shown in my own timezone.

---

What I'd like:

[image: img]

---

What I've got:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The city **Iceland** -> **Reykjavik** uses GMT+0 and does not currently observe daylight saving. This will do for now. However, if they were to start using daylight saving then all my meetings scheduled in that time would suddenly be wrong.